# Problema com imagem

Tags: java, imagem, javafx

Eu fiz um pequeno aplicativo para mostrar meu problema; sempre que o jogador fizer uma sequência na diagonal, ganha, caso ninguém faça isso, dá empate; não olhe para o fato de que o segundo jogador nunca vai ganhar... apenas fiz um exemplo para mostrar que ao ganhar ou dar empate, queria que as imagens aparecessem um pouquinho antes de serem anuladas; por exemplo, quando alguém ganha aparece uma imagem e a outra some, ao aparecer a mensagem do ganhador. Vejam. As duas imagens possuem tamanho 70 *pixels*... o código compila na boa. Olhem:

```
package example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Example extends Application{

    private final Button[] BUTTONS =  new Button[4];

    private boolean JOGADOR_UM = true;
    private boolean JOGADOR_DOIS = false;

    private static DropShadow DROPSHADOW = new DropShadow();

    private final String [][] MATRIZ = new String[2][2];
    private final String [] TABELA = new String[2];

    private final Image[] IMAGE = {
         new Image(Example.class.getResource("0.png").toString()),
         new Image(Example.class.getResource("1.png").toString();
    };

    public Parent createContent(){

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
        tilePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tilePane.setPrefColumns(2);

        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){

        BUTTONS[i] = new Button();
        BUTTONS[i].setPrefSize(90, 90);
        tilePane.getChildren().add(BUTTONS[i]);

        }


        BUTTONS[0].setOnAction((ActionEvent) ->{

            if(JOGADOR_UM== true){

                if(BUTTONS[0].getEffect() == null){

                BUTTONS[0].setGraphic(new ImageView(IMAGE[0]));
                BUTTONS[0].setEffect(DROPSHADOW);

                validarJogada();
                registrarJogada(0, "X");

                }

            } else{

                if(BUTTONS[0].getEffect() == null){
                BUTTONS[0].setGraphic(new ImageView(IMAGE[1]));
                BUTTONS[0].setEffect(DROPSHADOW);
                validarJogada();
                registrarJogada(0, "O");

                }   
            }

        });


        BUTTONS[1].setOnAction((ActionEvent) ->{

            if(JOGADOR_UM == true){

                if(BUTTONS[1].getEffect() == null){


                BUTTONS[1].setGraphic(new ImageView(IMAGE[0]));
                BUTTONS[1].setEffect(DROPSHADOW);

                validarJogada();
                registrarJogada(1, "X");

                }

            } else{

                if(BUTTONS[1].getEffect() == null){

                BUTTONS[1].setGraphic(new ImageView(IMAGE[1]));
                BUTTONS[1].setEffect(DROPSHADOW);
                validarJogada();
                registrarJogada(1, "O");

                }
            }


        });

        BUTTONS[2].setOnAction((ActionEvent) ->{

            if(JOGADOR_UM == true){

                if(BUTTONS[2].getEffect() == null){

                BUTTONS[2].setGraphic(new ImageView(IMAGE[0]));
                BUTTONS[2].setEffect(DROPSHADOW);

                validarJogada();
                registrarJogada(2, "X");

                }

            } else{

                if (BUTTONS[2].getEffect() == null){

                BUTTONS[2].setGraphic(new ImageView(IMAGE[1]));
                BUTTONS[2].setEffect(DROPSHADOW);
                validarJogada();
                registrarJogada(2, "O");


                }

            }

        });


        BUTTONS[3].setOnAction((ActionEvent) ->{

            if(JOGADOR_UM == true){

                if(BUTTONS[3].getEffect() == null){

                BUTTONS[3].setGraphic(new ImageView(IMAGE[0]));
                BUTTONS[3].setEffect(DROPSHADOW);

                validarJogada();
                registrarJogada(3, "X");

                }

            } else{

                if(BUTTONS[3].getEffect() == null){

                BUTTONS[3].setGraphic(new ImageView(IMAGE[1]));
                BUTTONS[3].setEffect(DROPSHADOW);
                validarJogada();
                registrarJogada(3, "O");

                }

            }

        });


        root.getChildren().add(tilePane);
        return root;

    }

    public void validarJogada(){

        if(JOGADOR_UM == true){

            JOGADOR_UM = false;
            JOGADOR_DOIS = true;

        }else{

            JOGADOR_UM = true;
            JOGADOR_DOIS = false;

        }

    }

    public void registrarJogada(int p, String jogada){

        if(p == 0){

            MATRIZ[0][0] = jogada;

        }else if(p == 1){

            MATRIZ[0][1] = jogada;

        }

        if(p == 2){

            MATRIZ[1][0] = jogada;

        }else if(p == 3){

            MATRIZ[1][1] = jogada;

        }

        verificarGanhador();

    }

    public void verificarGanhador(){

        TABELA[0] = MATRIZ[0][0] + MATRIZ[1][1];
        TABELA[1] = MATRIZ[1][0] + MATRIZ[0][1];

            for (String tabela: TABELA) {

        switch (tabela) {
            case "XX":
                ganhador("X");
                break;
            case "OO":
                ganhador("O");
                break;
        }
    }

    if (BUTTONS[0].getEffect()!= (null) &&

        BUTTONS[1].getEffect() != (null) &&
        BUTTONS[2].getEffect() != (null) &&
        BUTTONS[3].getEffect() != (null)){

            ganhador("XO");     
    }




    }

    public void ganhador(String ganhador){

        switch(ganhador){
            case "X":

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jogador 1 ganhou!");
                limparJogo();

                break;

            case "O":

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jogador 2 ganhou!");
                limparJogo();

                break;

            case "XO":

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Empatou");
                limparJogo();

                break;
        }

    }

    public void limparJogo(){


    BUTTONS[0].setGraphic(null);
    BUTTONS[1].setGraphic(null);
    BUTTONS[2].setGraphic(null);
    BUTTONS[3].setGraphic(null);


    BUTTONS[0].setEffect(null);
    BUTTONS[1].setEffect(null);
    BUTTONS[2].setEffect(null);
    BUTTONS[3].setEffect(null);


    for (String[] m : MATRIZ) {

        for (int i = 0; i<MATRIZ.length; i++) {
            m[i] = ("");
        }
    }

    JOGADOR_UM = true;
    JOGADOR_DOIS = false;


    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent(), 200, 200));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){launch(args);}

}
```

Comment: Voce quer exibir a imagem que está por baixo, caso sejam diferentes? la onde ta setGraphic voce pode setar a imagem do posiçao local

Comment: Sim... quero exibir, mas logo a seguir, devem "voltar para baixo", já que são diferentes.

Comment: Você pode demonstrar em código, Michel Simões.

Comment: Pessoal, quando aplicado em Swing, não ocorre esse problema; acho que é próprio do JavaFX, porque fiz a mudança pra ele. Isso já aconteceu antes. Deve ser algo relacionado ao ImageView... será?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muitas pesquisas, compreendi esse problema. Em Swing, e usando JOptioPane, não há problema; as imagens aparecem e só são anuladas ao se fechar a mensagem. Em JavaFX, usando o JOptionPane, ocorre o problema de anular as imagens antes de aparecer a mensagem. Mas se usarmos as mensagens próprias do JavaFX, fica tudo certo.

Ficaria assim:

`public void ganhador(String ganhador){

```
    switch(ganhador){
        case "X":

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText("Jogador 1 ganhou!");
            alert.showAndWait();
            limparJogo();

            break;

        case "O":

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText("Jogador 2 ganhou!");
            alert.showAndWait();
            limparJogo();


            break;

        case "XO":

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText("Empatou!");
            alert.showAndWait();
            limparJogo();

            break;
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Com base neste codigo postado, deve funcionar assim:

```
buttons[PrimeiroClick].setGraphic((new ImageView(imgs[Aleatorio[PrimeiroClick]])); 
buttons[SegundoClick].setGraphic((new ImageView(imgs[Aleatorio[SegundoClick]]));
```

Caso não seja, isso, tenta postar + do codigo.

Comment: Cara, não entendi... coloquei, mas nada aconteceu; editei o código. Dá uma olhada nele.

Comment: Quando aplicado em Swing, não ocorre esse problema; acho que é próprio do JavaFX, porque fiz a mudança pra ele. Isso já aconteceu antes. Deve ser algo relacionado ao ImageView... será?

Comment: Implementação e declaração default, deve ser.

Comment: Fiz uma jogo da velha que teve esse mesmo problema; espero que alguém me socorra. No Swing, ou utilizando números no JavaFx, no lugar de imagens, dá certo.